# How to define grammar for a sentence using pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'd like to define the grammar for my python script that parses server logs using the awesome python library pyparsing.

Here's my script, I've used alphas, alphanums, printables but they always only print the first word. I need to define the grammar such that even if the message is modified, it is parsed as a whole.

```
    #!/bin/python

    import string
    from pyparsing import *

    log = Word(printables)
    print(log)

    log1 = Word(alphanums+"-")
    print(log1)

    log_display = ("Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean 
    activities...")
    data = log.parseString(log_display)
    print(data.dump())
    print()
```

The output I get is always - 
W:(0123...)
W:(ABCD...)
['Starting']

Comment: Your parser only defines a single word, so that is why it only parses one word and then stops. If you want one or more words, then try `log = OneOrMore(Word(printables))` But this isn't much of a parser...

Comment: @PaulMcG - awesome. That did it! One question - How can I get them to appear as one message [" ... "]  and not `['Starting', 'Daily', '--apt', 'upgrade', 'and', 'clean', 'activities...']`??

Comment: If you wrap the `OneOrMore` with `originalTextFor`, (as in `log = originalTextFor(OneOrMore(Word(printables)))`), you will get the full string back. But now I'm really curious why you are even using pyparsing for this. Is this part of a larger parser? For instance, if you are looking for this expression because it parse the trailing part of a log line, after say a timestamp, process id, and program name, then you could also just use `restOfLine` and it will parse everything up to the next newline.

Comment: @PaulMcG yes exactly what you guessed! I just want to capture the trailing part of the log line after parsing the timestamp, username, process id etc. Thanks for the help , really appreciate it!